# missing prune Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

I wanted to delete that nnz_arr 0 value, consequently changing the other 2 arrays.

If i write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include<Eigen/SparseCore>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;


int main(){

    int nnz_size = 4;
    int num_rows = 3;

    vector<double> nnz_arr(nnz_size);
    nnz_arr.reserve(nnz_size+1);
    vector<int> col_arr(nnz_size);
    col_arr.reserve(nnz_size+1);
    vector<int> row_arr(num_rows+1);
    nnz_arr.reserve(num_rows+2);

    row_arr[0] = 0;
    row_arr[1] = 1;
    row_arr[2] = 2;
    row_arr[3] = 4;

    nnz_arr[0] = 1;
    nnz_arr[1] = 1;
    nnz_arr[2] = 0;
    nnz_arr[3] = 1;

    col_arr[0] = 0;
    col_arr[1] = 1;
    col_arr[2] = 1;
    col_arr[3] = 2;

    Map< SparseMatrix<double,RowMajor,int> > mat1 (num_rows, num_rows, nnz_size, row_arr.data(), col_arr.data(), nnz_arr.data());

    mat1.prune();
    
    for(int i=0; i< nnz_size; i++){
        cout << nnz_arr[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It says:

```
class "Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, 1, int>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0>>" has no member "prune"C/C++(135)
```

If i try changing the type of the matrix to:

```
SparseMatrix<double>
```

It still gives the same error.

If I use .pruned(), it finds it, but doesn't change anything in the output.

If i accept the fact that i cannot prune in-place, I write another mapper sparse matrix and use

```
mat1 = mat2.pruned()
```

It gives another error.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? A `Map` cannot allocate memory since it doesn't *own* its memory. So unless you know a-priori how many nonzero values you have (in which case pruning is mostly pointless anyway), the map cannot ensure that it can accept the new values. Just use a normal `SparseMatrix` and let Eigen handle the memory allocations

Comment: @Homer512 Just like in the example, i have a csr output which is not fully sparse, as there are some zerosn in nnz_arr. This is the result of an operation I wrote, lacking a correspective in C++. It actually exists for a dense output, but stores even more memory. I can even compute the number or acutal nnz that exists in that sparse output if you need it. I just don't know where they are. I thought prune would iterate over the sparse matrix and remove the nnz under the reference value (which i set as 0). Howevere it actually don't work. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: If you ask me why map, that's the way my program works. I'm just looking for a prune like function